# Can Singleton Object lead to degradation in performance even though we have multiple cores to serve request?

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

Multiple core allows multiple requests to be served in parallel.
Each request wants to access a method m() (non-synchronized method) in Singleton object.

As we have single instance, not all thread executing on different core can access method m() concurrently.

Let's say we have two thread T1 and T2 executing in parallel on different core.
And thread T1 is executing m() method currently. Thread T2 executing on another core has to wait until context switch or thread T1 is done executing m(), and then thread T2 gets change to execute m() method.

Due to which, though threads to serve request can be executed in parallel, it has to wait until thread context switch occurs or another thread is done executing on a method m().

So, doesn't singleton object affects performance ?

Answer (score 2):

You're wrong in your assumptions. You're saying:

> Each request wants to access a method m() (non-synchronized method) in
>   Singleton object. As we have single instance, not all thread can
>   access method m() concurrently.

This is incorrect. If the method is not synchronized, then it can be executed at the same time by as many threads as there are in the JVM. The fact that the object is a singleton has no impact on that; it's not relevant to the issue because you're not using synchronization.

So the answer is: having a singleton object with a non-synchronized method does not affect performance relative to having multiple objects

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. Threads can execute non-synchronized methods in parallel. 
Think of a method as a set of instructions that each thread will execute, in its own stack. So unless these instructions interfere with global state/each other there is nothing preventing threads running on different cores to execute in parallel.

Think of analogy, let's say you and your friend have instruction to make yourself a sandwich. If you use different ingredients there is nothing preventing you both at the same time making a sandwich.